# css:active is not working in firefox 25

Tags: css

Active property is not working in Firefox; I used this code:

```
#selec:active{background-color:red;}
```

The property works in Chrome, but not working in Firefox.

Comment: 1. It's Firefox. 2. Can you provide a bit more detail and code, perhaps in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Otherwise it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you have really understood what `:active` means in CSS. It applies style right at the moment when you are clicking. So it those styles wont last long if the page refreshes.

Even though it is not much big deal,  there is an order to style these if you applying `:hover` `:link` and `:visited`.

Please check whether you followed them

```
a:link { /* Essentially means a[href], or that the link actually goes somewhere */
  color: blue;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
a:active {
  color: red;
}
```